# Spring ControllerAdvice does not return response body?

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, controller-advice

I have the following `ControllerAdvice`, that handles `JsonParseException` (I use Spring and Jackson)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerExceptionHandler  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(JsonParseException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidJson(JsonParseException ex, WebRequest request){
    Map<String,Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
    body.put("message","Invalid Json");

    return new ResponseEntity(body, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 }
}
```

Fore some reason, It doesn't work when I send a bad json request to the server, only returns 400. When I change the `HttpStatus`, it still returns 400 so it seems like the advice doesn't really run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` already implements a lot of different ExceptionHandlers. `HttpMessageNotReadableException` is one of them:

```
else if (ex instanceof HttpMessageNotReadableException) {
            HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
            return handleHttpMessageNotReadable((HttpMessageNotReadableException) ex, headers, status, request);
        }
```

Simply remove the inheritance:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonParseException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> handleInvalidJson(JsonParseException ex, WebRequest request){
        Map<String,Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        body.put("message","Invalid Json");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. I set the headers in @ExceptionHandler method and those headers come ok. No matter what I do the body is always empty.

Comment: @user3852017 I'm facing the same issue, It looks like it could set the status but not the response body. I'm not even using any inheritance.

Comment: It works for me. I want to keep default response body and just modify the status code. I use "response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());" only and don't extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

Comment: Same problem here. Removing inheritance did not help.